# How to send email in wordpress with more than one attachments

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, attachments, wp-mail

In my plugin, there is a contact us form through which users can upload multiple files and it will be uploaded into `wp-contents/uploads/2014/10` folder. Uploading is working, but now I need to send email to admin with this uploaded files and entered user data. I don't know how to send mail with attachments.

The code I've tried so far is:

```
if(isset($_POST['Save'])){
 /* store post user data to variables */
 if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload'))
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
       $files = $_FILES['my_files'];
         $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);
foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($files['name'][$key]) {
    $file = array(
      'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
      'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
      'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
      'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
      'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
    );
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload($file, $upload_overrides);
     $url[] = $movefile['url'];
  }
}

$to  = 'exampleadmin@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Contact Us';
    $message =" Haiii";

  $headers[] = 'From: '.get_option( 'blogname' ).' <fromid@gmail.com>';
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'my_custom_email_content_type' );
    if(wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $url ))
    echo 'Mail send';
    else
     echo 'Failed';
function my_custom_email_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
```

This doesn't send any mail also shows error

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_custom_email_content_type' not found or invalid function name

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if that will solve all your problems, but:

Generally nicely formatted code is easier to debug. E.g. your code is missing the closing brace. Besides it is better to write if/else(if) statements with braces. Nice indentation helps too. I'd suggest reading the [WordPress - PHP Coding Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php).

Regarding your code:

- As noted at the [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) codex page the [`wp_mail_content_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type) filter should be removed after adding it to avoid problems.
- The file(s) of the `$attachment` parameter have to be given as path.

I've updated your code a bit:

```
if( isset( $_POST[ 'Save' ] ) ) {

    function my_custom_email_content_type( $content_type ) {
        return 'text/html';
    }

    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }

    $files = $_FILES[ 'my_files' ];
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

    $attachments = array();

    foreach ( $files['name'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $files[ 'name' ][ $key ] ) {
            $file = array(
                'name'     => $files[ 'name' ][ $key ],
                'type'     => $files[ 'type' ][ $key ],
                'tmp_name' => $files[ 'tmp_name' ][ $key ],
                'error'    => $files[ 'error' ][ $key ],
                'size'     => $files[ 'size' ][ $key ]
            );
            $movefile = wp_handle_upload(
                $file,
                $upload_overrides
            );
            $attachments[] = $movefile[ 'file' ];
        }
    }

    $to        = 'exampleadmin@gmail.com';
    $subject   = 'Contact Us';
    $message   = 'Haiii';
    $headers[] = 'From: ' . get_option( 'blogname' ) . ' <fromid@gmail.com>';

    add_filter(
        'wp_mail_content_type',
        'my_custom_email_content_type'
    );
    $wp_mail_return = wp_mail(
        $to,
        $subject,
        $message,
        $headers,
        $attachments
    );
    if( $wp_mail_return ) {
        echo 'Mail send';
    } else {
        echo 'Failed';
    }
    remove_filter(
        'wp_mail_content_type',
        'my_custom_email_content_type'
    );
}
```